# Remove Function doesn't work during onAppend Function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the [lazyframe](https://github.com/viktorbergehall/lazyframe) plugin to lazy load youtube videos in a WP installation. Lazyframe creates a responsive placeholder for embedded content and requests it when the user interacts with it.

It also includes a `onAppend: function(e) {}` Callback for when the iframe is appended to DOM.

Now I'm trying to remove a image from the DOM during the onAppend function. The onAppend Callback functions works fine. To test it, i used the following code, wich alerts successfully:

```
    ...     
    onLoad: function(e) {},
    onAppend: function(e) {
                                    
    // Place functions here
    alert('Hello World');
                                                         
    }
    },
    ...
```

To remove the image from the DOM, i tried the following remove() function, unfortunately it doesn't work. **Any idea how to solve the Problem including a short info why this doesn't work?**

```
    ...     
    onLoad: function(e) {},
    onAppend: function(e) {

    // Place Functions here   
    $("#lf-img").remove();

    }
    },
    ...
```

**Edit:**

After a quick input i also tried to check if the element exists. I put a id to the img tag and checked the existence with the following code. It returns "Element exists"

```
    if(document.getElementById("lf-img")){
        alert("Element exists");
    } else {
        alert("Element does not exist");
    }
```

**Edit 2: (Problem solved)**

Changing `$("#lf-img").remove();` to `jQuery("#lf-img").remove();` solved the problem.

Comment: Please check  $(".featured-thumb") exists when you are removing it.
To test it, verify its length. If it is more than 1, it exists.

Comment: Are you manually hiding the video thumbnail when the video loads? Could you not use the `data-thumbnail` [option](https://github.com/viktorbergehall/lazyframe#element-specific-options) with the plugin?

Comment: @Jackson - im using a custom thumb -  not the youtube thumb. This image is below the video. The problem is, that my thumb size bigger then the video size, So im trying to remove it after the video starts. If (if - else) there is no video url set in my backend it displays the image...

Comment: @Learningbydoing Do you get a JS error in the browser?

Comment: Nothing... Now im trying to check if the element exists like @Nitesh wrote

Comment: @Nitesh and Jackson - look at my edit above. The element exist... but the js code dont work - no errors in the console...?

Comment: you checked this code inside "onAppend" callback?

Comment: Yes - but right now i found the problem. i changed `$("#lf-img").remove();`
 to `jQuery("#lf-img").remove();` and it works. Is this ok? I use the js plugin in a wordpress installation  - i think that was causing the problem. But im not sure if the change from  `$` to  `jQuery` is ok?

Comment: Using 'jQuery' instead of '$' should do the trick for wordpress plugin.

For more info, you can check this:
https://digwp.com/2011/09/using-instead-of-jquery-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using 'jQuery' instead of '$' should do the trick for wordpress plugin**.

For more info, you can check this:
https://digwp.com/2011/09/using-instead-of-jquery-in-wordpress/

Also, if you want to use some other keyword for jQuery object, you can do like this:

```
$jQ = jQuery.noConflict()
```